# Error Code 0 when Mass Updating Content using Postman API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, content-builder

I'm trying to do a mass update of Content using API via PostMan (Collection Runner). Specifically, I'm trying to add multiple tags to my Content by using a data file to feed the attributes in Collection runner. I'm using a CSV file, which looks something like this;

```
Content_Id, Tag_Id,
1234, 301
5678, "301, 401"
```

I started a Collection in PostMan where the first API requests the Access token and then the second API is a Patch API to update the content with the tags that I want. Again, this pulls from the CSV file. Also, I added Pre-request scripts which parse the data in the Tag_Id column.

The API to request the access always works, but then the PATCH API to update the Content with tag returns the following:

```
{
    "documentation": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm",
    "errorcode": 0,
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

I know the Patch API is formatted correctly, because when I hard code the values in it works. But it's just when i try to use the data file do i get an error. I checked the console and the Tag Id's seem to be flowing in fine....

For reference, the below is my PATCH API - Access Token has been modified:

```
PATCH /asset/v1/content/assets/{{Content_Id}}? HTTP/1.1
Host: https://mcwrpx6qhhjx04wnb-0nr7sd1g81.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn5.egJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iOiJaRDlta2RNcnZGUWFjam1wbU1melpHb1UiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJwczZ1NjZpOXNzb3B2cDkyM2NxcXEzd2MiLCJlaWQiOjEwMDAxNTkxOCwic3RhY2tfa2V5IjoiUzEwIiwicGxhdGZvcm1fdmVyc2lvbiI6MiwiY2xpZW50X3R5cGUiOiJTZXJ2ZXJUb1NlcnZlciJ9.ORvvs8Bw8LhYXabqmZw_F48QApZuDc5N5a22CfHWjZM.jyeIyueu9VUX4k_GcMtjD7iFTiu_99Cmmw2MyYlXe51VuQT5UNZ74fMmyVz3HBcDy73aPDDmdpdX4S7aIizMv2excLfHab7hCm04mC1zr372iP3LfD5tb0JsoW-oob7HWgr1RqxgPGH-
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Tags": [{{Tag_Id}}]
}
```

Comment: I just ran your entire run against some dummy content I had and it worked perfectly.  It sounds like the issue may be something with how the call is set up in the runner versus what you are running manually. I wish I could give more, but without being able to replicate the issue, I can't give much more insight.

Comment: I think i solved it! So my previous file that I was using was a UTF-8 CSV, after switching to just CSV it seems to work...

I also did some Console.log testing and when i was using the UTF-8 CSV, the Content_Id value was "undefined" even though the Tag_Id value was coming in as normal.